# Sorting tuples in haskell lists

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'd like to sort a list of tuples by the third or fourth element (say c or d) in the list of type:

```
myList = [(a,b,c,d,e)]
```

I know if the tuple is of type `(a,b)` I can use the following approach:

```
mySort xmyList = sortBy (compare `on` snd) x
```

But the type of sortBy will not work on tuples with length greater than two (so obviously  there is no point writing an accessor function for `thd` or `fth`) :

```
(a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: The type of `sortBy` says nothing at all about tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the type of sortBy will not work on tuples with length greater
>   than two

No, it actually works for any list. For instance, if you want to sort on `c`, just do:

```
mySort xmyList = sortBy (compare `on` (\(a,b,c,d,e) -> c)) x
```

or

```
mySort xmyList = sortBy (comparing thirdOf5) x
   where thirdOf5 (_,_,c,_,_) = c
```